# Why parent element click event fires automatically when child textbox is clicked/focus in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have following HTML structure

```
[Checkbox] [Text] [Input element (Show if check-box is checked)]
```

---

```
<span class='spGrpContainer'>
  <label id='stepGH_Group1' class='lblStep GHSteps lblGroupheader' stepid='1' stepname='Group1' childcontainer='ulGH_grp1Steps'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' onchange="Javascript:HideUnHideSubItems();" /><span class='sptext spGHStepName'>Check Me</span></label>
    <label class='lblRanking' style='display: none;'><input id='rnkbox_Scr' class='txtImportance' type='number' min='0' max='100' step='1' value='' /></label>
  </label>
</span>
```

When input element click, the checkbox is automatic hide in `Safari browser`. In all other major browser like Chrome, IE, Firefox it's working nice.
[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgnecsfo/12/)

I also tried `event.stopPropagation()` for resolving event bubbling, but its didn't helpful. [Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgnecsfo/16/)

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you need `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Tushar: I tried with "event.stopPropagation()" method but it's did't work for me . Check Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgnecsfo/16/

Answer (score 2):

Click is an event that bubbles up.
You might want to take a look at the JavaScript Documentation by MDN about event bubbling.
http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

`event.stopPropagation()` should prevent it from happening.
[Stop propagation documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Yes, I tried with "event.stopPropagation()" method but it's did't work for me . Check Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgnecsfo/16/

Comment: I think, I am wrong here. Because "event.stopPropagation()" is working with when we alert somthing. Check Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgnecsfo/17/. Can you please help/suggest to works without alert?